# UiNavigationController shows default back button after 2 segues in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have a problem that I can´t find solution.

I have a UINavigationController with a modified back button with text "modifiedBack".

Then I have 3 view controllers:

-The first view controller:
is the root view controller of the Navigation Controller. I changed there the navigation Item (in the pic you can see)
No back button is shown. OK.
In it, it has a button to make a show segue to the second View controller.

-In the second View Controller: 
I see back button like "modifiedBack". OK
I have another button to make a show segue to the third View Controller.

-In the third View Controller:
I see back button like standard "back". Wrong

How could I solve this? I need this for my project to change the stock back blue button with an colored and different button, but i can´t.

I post picture of it:
[image: picture]

Thank you!

Comment: you want "modifiedBack" text back button in last 2 screens ?

Comment: I want "modifiedBack" in all view controllers that I am making show segues.

Comment: I auto solved this for me, in each view controller, I have to add a navigation Item and modify it like I want, so the next view controller I show has it.